# How to insert a row to an existing auto increment table in oracle?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I created my db tables with hibernate, and my user class has an auto generated id like as follwos.

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_Id")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
```

I am trying to insert a user from toad console also I add the user_id value as manually. When I want to insert a new  user from my application, I get an error as follow,

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (TDM.SYS_C001668192) violated
```

I have to insert some values from database with a procedure, so how to insert new rows with using the existing sequence or id (whatever)?

**UPDATE:**

I resolve the problem thanks to  @Afridi as follow.

firstly, I added sequence annotation to user_id

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "t_user_id_seq_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "t_user_id_seq_generator", sequenceName = "t_user_seq")
    @Column(name = "user_Id")
    private int userId;
```

after that I called it like that;

```
insert into t_user (user_id, username) values(T_USER_SEQ.nextval, 'newUser');
```

I checked it this sql;

```
select * from user_sequences where sequence_name = 'T_USER_SEQ';
```

Comment: use this:
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_entity_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="MY_ENTITY_SEQ")
private Long id;

Comment: can I access already existing value right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem thanks to @Afridi as follow.

firstly, I added sequence annotation to user_id

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "t_user_id_seq_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "t_user_id_seq_generator", sequenceName = "t_user_seq")
@Column(name = "user_Id")
private int userId;
```

after that I called it like that;

```
insert into t_user (user_id, username) values(T_USER_SEQ.nextval, 'newUser');
```

I checked it this sql;

```
select * from user_sequences where sequence_name = 'T_USER_SEQ';
```

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate automatically fills column markes with `@GeneratedValue`. From doc:

> The @GeneratedValue annotation specifies that the entity identifier
>   value is automatically generated using an identity column, a database
>   sequence, or a table generator. Hibernate supports the @GeneratedValue
>   mapping even for UUID identifiers.

You can set type of `@GeneratedValue`. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators

Answer (score 1):

This have nothing to do with `@GeneratedValue` annotation. Even if you have annotated your field with this annotation and you provide your own id, it will use that instead of generating it.

You're getting this error because of `@Id` annotation. This annotation makes your field `userId` unique. It's a primary key so you can't have duplicate entries.

What you can do is instead of calling `session.save(entity)` you can call `session.update(entity)` or `session.saveOrUpdate(entity)`. It will either save it if it doesn't exists, otherwise update/overwrite it.

Comment: you're right but i don't try update something, I am trying to move some values from another database to my own database with JDBC, but my current values were created with a procedure. not with my application. So some problem occures for duplicate ids. got it?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate use a sequence to generate ids for `@GeneratedValue` field, and Hibernate will cache some ids which is selected from that sequence. So when you manually assign id for new row, this id may violate the cached id.